# Ho to toggle checkbox by pressing space while focused on label having tabindex?

Tags: html, checkbox, label

I'm widely using labels associated with checkbox inputs in my html. It allows user to click on the wide label and get what he wants - checkbox toggle. I want to achieve similar behaviour by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle the checkbox while being focused on the label. To make label focusable I add `tabindex="0"` to labels. I also don't want checkboxes to be focusable so I add `tabindex="-1"` to inputs.

Here are two examples, one is using label tag wrapping, another is using `for` attribute.

```html
<input type="button" value="Click then press tab." /><br/>
<label tabindex="0">Accept terms <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/></label><br/>
<label for="MyCheckbox" tabindex="0">Accept terms</label> <input type="checkbox" id="MyCheckbox" tabindex="-1"/>
```

I'm interested in a possibility of achieving desired behaviour without any javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not set tabindex to label at all. Instead, set tabindex only to checkbox and place it outside the label. Works for me on Safari.

[image: Gif presenting Safari behaviour]

```html
<input type="button" value="Click then press tab"><br>
<label for="myCheckbox">This is label</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: There are some cases where it would be useful to be able to completely hide the checkbox input itself (with `display: none;`) leaving only the label visible. In that case we would have to be able to focus on the label (with `tabindex="0"`) and mark the checkbox by pressing space, however I don't think the last part is possible without JS :/